# настройка фигмы для начинающих web developer

Tags: веб-программирование

изучаю html и css, столкнулась с такой проблемой, скачала макет , но могу полностью редактировать макет и двигать предметы, очень неудобно , как вкл режим чтения для фигмы? у меня мак

Comment: Режим чтения? В фигме сейчас есть новый режим - `Dev`, в нем вы не можете редактировать макет, но вам придется включать и выключать его ибо некоторого функционала он не предоставляет.